# Who Made my Bike?

Tags: identify-this-bike

Pictures of bike:

[image]

[image]

http://s1292.photobucket.com/user/Space_Scumbag/media/My%20Bike/P8290052_zps195adaa1.jpg.html?sort=3&o=2

So I've had this bike for many years now, and I'm finally selling it as I have another one which fits me better. But there's no trademarks on it and I have no idea who manufactured it. There used to be stickers on it which may have had the manufacturer's name on it, but they looked stupid so I took them off. The make would be useful as it would give me all the information I'll need to give when I sell it. Any help is much appreciated, thanks. The seat isn't original by the way. The old one was just plain black.

Comment: Please include the images directly on stackexchange. Also, take pictures of the headtube area, drop outs, bottom bracket area, etc. and try to find a serial number on it there. Also, what components are equipped on it if they're original might help too.

Comment: It doesn't look anything special. It's a bike. Sell it as such.

Comment: @JamesMorris - Please be civil on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: It's pretty generic, and does not look like it was an expensive bike originally.  The quality of the components (hubs, shifters, etc) is probably more important than the manufacturer of the frame.  If you can figure out the derailleur brand that's the thing to mention in an ad.

Comment: Sometimes a photo of the bottom bracket might help.  A few companies use special codes in the serial numbers.  Im also going to asume this bike is second hand.  However I find it odd that you dont know the maker of it when you took the stickers off.  Mixed bag of parts it looks like.  Are those plastic brake levers?  The water bottle cage looks like a cheap one on a older bike I have where the bottle has a grove to slide on that.

Answer (score 1):

In US it would be Magna o Huffy, a 20 years old department store bike made in Taiwan with no value today. For sure it's not a real brand bike. Indestructible but butt ugly.